# Ruby Script: Remove duplicates from puts Loop

Tags: ruby, pattern-matching, duplicates

This is my code

```
pattern = /066-\d\d\d\-\d\d\d\-\d\d\d\-\d\d\ /
Dir['c:/WurtsmithClean/DRCs/*.txt'].each do |file|
   next unless File.file?(file)
       File.open(file) do |f|
           f.each_line do |line|
               if line.match(pattern)
                   ln = line.match(pattern)
                   file.gsub!('c:/WurtsmithClean/DRCs/', '')
                   file.gsub!('txt', 'pdf')
                   puts file + "," + ln.to_s
               end
           end
       end
end
```

So this script looks for a matching pattern of "066-###-###-###-##" in all text documents in the c:/WurtsmithClean/DRCs/ directory on every line and outputs the file name and the match both separated by a comma for CSV import.

BUT i have been trying to figure out how to remove duplicates of the matches, as it finds multiple matches with the same numbers in the same file name. I want these removed. I have tried using the UNIQ() method but it seems to only work on arrays. While the entire output is technically an array after the loop finishes I dont know how to reference the final output as an array and remove the duplicates.

Here is the sample of how the output is now:

```
066-018-400-001-00 DRC #26.pdf,066-018-400-001-00 
066-018-400-001-00 DRC #26.pdf,066-018-400-001-00 
066-019-100-001-00 DRC #19.pdf,066-019-100-001-00 
066-019-100-001-00 DRC #19.pdf,066-019-100-001-00 
066-019-100-001-00 DRC #19.pdf,066-019-100-001-00 
066-019-100-001-00 DRC.pdf,066-019-100-001-00 
066-020-100-001-00 DRC #20.pdf,066-020-100-001-00 
066-020-100-001-00 DRC #20.pdf,066-020-100-001-00 
066-020-100-001-00 DRC #20.pdf,066-020-100-001-00 
066-020-100-001-00 DRC #20.pdf,066-020-100-001-00
```

I want it to output like this (No Duplicates):

```
066-018-400-001-00 DRC #26.pdf,066-018-400-001-00 
066-019-100-001-00 DRC #19.pdf,066-019-100-001-00 
066-019-100-001-00 DRC.pdf,066-019-100-001-00 
066-020-100-001-00 DRC #20.pdf,066-020-100-001-00
```

Comment: CarySwoveland no that doesn't work I need to use match as find will output the match and the rest of the line after it.. i just want the numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill the array along the way. And then use `uniq` on it once you're done.

```
matches = []
pattern = /066-\d\d\d\-\d\d\d\-\d\d\d\-\d\d\ /
Dir['c:/WurtsmithClean/DRCs/*.txt'].each do |file|
  next unless File.file?(file)
  File.open(file) do |f|
    f.each_line do |line|
      if line.match(pattern)
        ln = line.match(pattern)
        file.gsub!('c:/WurtsmithClean/DRCs/', '')
        file.gsub!('txt', 'pdf')
        matches << file + "," + ln.to_s
      end
    end
  end
end
matches.uniq.each { |match| puts match }
```

Comment: thx this works.. i needed to put a "puts" in front of "matches.uniq!" though

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could do something like this, for each file:

First, I'll make a small file for testing:

```
FNAME= 'test1'

text =<<_
pig11
cat12
hat13
rat14
dog15
_

File.write(FNAME, text)
```

Now let's look for the first line of the file that matches the pattern `/t\d+/` (say), and then extract the number:

```
pattern = /t(\d+)/
File.open(FNAME) do |f|
  ln = f.find { |l| l =~ pattern }
  puts "found '#{ln[pattern,1]}' in line #{ln.chomp} in file #{FNAME}" if ln
end
  #=> found '12' in line cat12 in file test1
```